# Creating a regex to replace each matched character of a string with same character

Tags: javascript, regex

In my application, I have an alphanumeric string being passed into my function. This string is typically 17 characters, but not always. I'm trying to write a regex that matches all but the last 4 characters in the string, and replaces them with X (to mask it).

For example

```
Input: HGHG8686HGHG8686H

Output: XXXXXXXXXXXXX686H
```

The Regex I wrote to perform the replace on the string is as follows

```
[a-zA-Z0-9].{12}
```

Code:

```
const maskedString = string.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9].{12}/g, 'X');
```

The issue I'm having is that it's replacing all but the last 4 characters in the string with just that single X. It doesn't know to do that for every matched character. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there something special you want to do with non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: The trick is to use match groups. First match on the last 4 alphanumeric characters, lets call this Group1.  Then match on EITHER the START PLUS TWO characters OR any ONE character.  Then simply substitute each match with X and append the value of Group1 to the end.  Refer my answer below for the regex string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look ahead (`?=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) to make sure there are at least four following characters.

```js
const regex = /.(?=....)/g;
//             ^             MATCH ANYTHING
//              ^^^^^^^^     THAT IS FOLLOWED BY FOUR CHARS

function fix(str) { return str.replace(regex, 'X'); }

const test = "HGHG8686HGHG8686H";

// CODE BELOW IS MERELY FOR DEMO PURPOSES
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
function populate() { output.textContent = fix(input.value); }
input.addEventListener("input", populate);
input.value = test;
populate();
```

```html
<p><label>Input: </label><input id="input"></p>
<p>Output: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

A non-regexp solution:

```js
const test = "HGHG8686HGHG8686H";

function fix(str) {
  return 'X'.repeat(str.length - 4) + str.slice(-4);
}
  
console.log(fix(test));
```

You will not find [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) in IE.

Comment: Sir what if we have a some other character other than alphanumeric, this will replace that also. And the question says it replaces all but last 4 and wants to do it for every matching characters. Just a though that struck me. :)

Comment: @Manish The question mentions that the input is going to be alphanumeric, but doesn't describe what if anything should be done if characters are not alphanumeric.

Comment: This is fantastic. This is the cleanest solution by far.

Answer (score 3):

you can use a function inside replace to do this, something like this will do:

```js
var str = "HGHG8686HGHG8686H"
var regexp = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=....)/g;
var modifiedStr = str.replace(regexp, function ($2) {
    return ('X'.repeat($2.length +1));
});
console.log(modifiedStr);
```

Comment: Of `'X'.repeat(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

The simple version: (Easier to read)

```
const maskedString = string.replace(/(.{4})$|(^(..)|(.))/g, 'X\1'); // or X$1
```

Now using: [a-zA-Z0-9]

```
const maskedString = string.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})$|(^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}))/g, 'X\1'); // or X$1
```

Note: The reason i match on the START PLUS TWO characters is to offset the first match. (The final 4 characters that are appended at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using following method:

```js
      var str = "HGHG8686HGHG8686H"

      var replaced=''

      var match = str.match(/.+/)
    
      for(i=0;i<match[0].length-4;i++){
        
          str = match[0][i]
        
          replaced += "X"
        
      }

      replaced += match[0].substr(match[0].length-4)

      console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: in this case suppose i have a special character in the string. So your solution will output the string before that special character only. try with this `"HGHG&686HGHG8686H"`

Comment: But I think `replaced += str.replace(/./, "X")` is exactly equivalent to `replaced += "X"`.